# getting the text inside a tag from meteor expression

Tags: meteor

The code below suppose to get the text insdie of the list, so if task1 is clicked then an alert should say task1, if task2 is clicked, then the alert says text2...
But when I click on any of the link, no alert shows up let along its message. I must be doing something wrong. Pleas help. Thanks

```js
Template.mainMenu.helpers({
  menuItems: [
    {menuItem: "task1"},
    {menuItem: "task2"},
    {menuItem: "task3"},
    {menuItem: "task4"},
    {menuItem: "task5"},
    {menuItem: "task6"},
    {menuItem: "task7"}
    ]
});

Template.mainMenu.events({
  'click .menuItem': function(){
    alert(event.target.menuItem.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<template name="mainMenu">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <section class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="list-group">
          {{#each menuItems}}
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item menuItem">
              <img src="/abc.png">
              {{menuItem}} <span class="badge">&#x3e;</span>
            </a>
          {{/each}}
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined argument (event) of function.
Below example will help you understand that your code was throwing uncaught errors.

```
Template.mainMenu.events({
  'click .menuItem': function(event){
     try{
       alert(event.target.menuItem.value);
     } catch (e){
       alert(e)
     }
  }
});
```

---

### Update

Add `data-value={{menuItem}}` to link and then try to get this value using jQuery:

```
<template name="mainMenu">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <section class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="list-group">
          {{#each menuItems}}
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item menuItem" data-value={{menuItem}}>
              <img src="/abc.png">
              {{menuItem}} <span class="badge">&#x3e;</span>
            </a>
          {{/each}}
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

Template.mainMenu.events({
  'click .menuItem': function(event){
     try{
       alert($(event.currentTarget).data('value'));
     } catch (e){
       alert(e)
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: Correct. `event.target.menuItem` doesn't exist. It is not clear for me what value you would like to get ? You would like to get name of task (task1, task2, task3, etc ) ?

Comment: http://meteorpad.com/pad/mJyouLs3BzKACvqDB/so-getting%20the%20text%20inside%20a%20tag%20from%20meteor%20expression